# Question related to the sigma during expectation in probability

Tags: summation

How is this below possible:

$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/i = \infty $

Comment: updated the question made a terrible mistake @Hakim

Comment: It's also off-topic because you haven't shown any effort to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i}=\infty \\ \\ \text{ AND  } \\ \\ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}=\infty$$

BUT NOT:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i}=\infty$$

**EDIT:**

If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ would converge,from the Cauchy criterion,there would be a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m>n \geq n_0:$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+ \dots +\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{2}$$

Specifically:

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+n}<\frac{1}{2}$$

But:

$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n+n} \geq \frac{1}{n+n} +\frac{1}{n+n}  \dots+\frac{1}{n+n} =\frac{n}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore,the series diverges.

Comment: yaa why so i have updated the question that was a big error however

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan I edited my answer!!!